# Show that a set is closed 2

Tags: general-topology

I want to show that 
$I = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^3 : 1 \leq x_1 \leq 3, 0 \leq x_2, x_3 \leq -1\}$
is closed by showing that the complement is open with open balls.

But how can I do that?
Thanks

Comment: I have done this: you cannot say that there is for any point x in I an open ball with center z and radius r. Because if we take X1=3, then we cannot find a r such that ||x-z|| < r. But I want to show that it is closed, so I thought that R3\I is open. But I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Can you write down which elements are in $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus I$?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show, that a subset $A$ of some metric space is open, you pick a point $x\in A$ and try to find such radius $r_x>0$, that an open ball $B(x, r_x)$ is contained in $A$. It's a basic procedure in all metric spaces and here it will work exactly the same way.

You need to take an arbitrary point $x\in (\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus I)$ and show that for some $r>0$ a set of form $\{y\in \mathbb{R}^3: \|x-y\|<r\}$ is contained in $(\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus I)$.

Comment: But don't you have to check it for every x or is it enough to do it for one? And how can you do it for every x?

Comment: You do have to check it for every $x$. However, notice that taking the distance between our $x\in (\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus I)$ and $I$ suffices, since the inequality in open ball (the set I've mentioned earlier) is strict. Or you can take half of this distance, just to make sure.